# Location of SharePoint Custom ASPX forms

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have always wanted to know where exactly the custom list forms are stored in SharePoint. I would rather do the editing with a text editor rather than use SharePoint designer.

Please let me know where they are if you know where it is.

The version my company is using is SharePoint 2007 WSS 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you have edited it already in SharePoint Designer, if you have, it is stored in the database and you cannot open it with a text editor. Otherwise, it is stored on the file system of each WFE server, this is what is called a "ghosted" file, meaning that the original file is not stored for each list instance, but rather the main master copy is used for all of them. Although you can edit it directly, this is highly unadvised, as the change will apply to all lists of the type, existing and future, you will need to make the change on all servers and any future service pack can potentially undo your changes.

Comment: I accept the point partially because you can have custom pages created in form of list definitions and they would not alter the master ghosted copy. thier is a error in your post "the change will apply to all lists of the type, existing " the changes will never apply on existing lists whose instance has been create this will impact all future custom lists

Comment: Not exactly, if you edit the ASPX file itself, it will affect the existing lists as well, as long as they are ghosted, we used to apply custom designs like this, in the old days :)

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in database hence their is no way to edit a  custom list forms other than share point desginer whose instance is already created. Other option is to create a list definition  [Custom site definition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287930%28office.12%29.aspx)